# Why is my mousePressEvent called twice?

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qtgui

I want to make a QLabel clickable and followed [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Make-a-QLabel-Clickable) "how-to". I was not sure how to get this piece of code into my GUI (I am quite newbie to qt). What I did was:

1. I created a new class (just copy/paste of `ClickableLabel` from the link, but I changed the signal to `clicked(QMouseEvent* event)`)
2. I added a QLabel to my GUI and "promoted" it to a `ClickableLable`
3. I connected the signal to a slot of my main window where I `std::cout` some stuff:

   ```
   connect(this->ui->label,SIGNAL(clicked(QMouseEvent*)),
           this,SLOT(on_label_clicked(QMouseEvent*)));
   ```

It seems to work. The problem is that each time I click on the label the `mousePressedEvent` gets called twice. I also tried `mouseReleasedEvent` but its the same.

Any ideas what could go wrong?

EDIT: Here is my modified `ClickableLable`:

```
class MyClickableLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyClickableLabel(QWidget* parent=0);
        ~GBoardLabel();
    signals:
        void clicked(QMouseEvent* event);
    protected:
        void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
};
MyClickableLabel::MyClickableLabel(QWidget* parent) : QLabel(parent) {this->setText("");}
MyClickableLabel::~MyClickableLabel() {}
void MyClickableLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    std::cout << "CLICKED R" << std::endl;
    std::cout << event->type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << event->pos().x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << event->pos().y() << std::endl;
    emit clicked(event);
}
```

The `cout`s in the in the above method I added only later and realized that the `mouseReleaseEvent` is actually only called once. But when I connect the `clicked` to a slot of my mainwindow, this slot recieves the event twice.

Then I removed the `connect` statement and to my surprise the signal is still emited and recieved (only once). I am a bit puzzled how this works, because I am pretty sure that I do not mistakenly have a `connect` anywhere in the code.

My label is working, but I would like to understand what is going on. Actually I am not 100% sure anymore that I didn't use some Qt creator feature make the connection. However, I have no idea where to find such connections. For example, I have a `QButton` on the same main window. In the gui editor I right clicked it and then "show slots"->"clicked()"->"OK" and automatically a method called `on_pushButton_clicked()` is created, but I have no idea, where this is called / how the button's signal is connected to this method. On the other hand, I do not get the `MyClickableLabel::clicked(QMouseEvent*)` listed in the list of slots for my label, thus I don't think I created the connection this way...

Comment: Not sure that it is related but strange they are not calling QLabel::mousePressEvent(event); in  ClickableLabel::mousePressEvent before doing other actions (emitting signal in your case)

Comment: Can you show us your reimplementation of `mousePressEvent()`?

Comment: @JonHarper Yes I can

Comment: Have you tried testing the signal without emitting `QMouseEvent *`? P.S. Regarding auto connecting signals-to-slots: only a private slot following the pattern "_q_on_[signal_name]" (IIRC) will connect automatically. There's more to this, but basically, slots don't connect themselves unless you're very specific about it.

Comment: @JonHarper The mainwinow`s slot is indeed private. I started with a new project (Qt Createor 3.3.2/ Qt 5.4.1) and this time I did not connect "manually" at all and the connection is made again, if the slot just hast the right name and signature. I still did not find any official documentation on this feature, but I found [this post](http://qtway.blogspot.de/2010/08/automatic-connections-using-qt-signals.html).

Comment: @tobi303: great info. Thank you. If you make the slot protected, this should no longer be an issue, or you can keep it private for the autoconnect. I'm definitely interested in using this.

Comment: @JonHarper Yes, it is pretty cool. I just do not like that the connection does not show up explicitly in my code, which can cause some confusion ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it, but I do not really understand what is going on...

It was not the `mousePressEvent` that was fired twice, but my `on_label_clicked` slot recieved the event twice.

I removed the `connect` statement and now the `on_label_clicked` is called only once per click. It seems like, there is something going on under the hood. Maybe when the slot is called `on_label_clicked` it gets automatically ("qtmatically") connected to the mouse events emmited from the child called `label` ?

**EDIT**: Still didnt find the official docs, but [this blog](http://qtway.blogspot.de/2010/08/automatic-connections-using-qt-signals.html) explains it quite nicely. In summary, one just needs to use the naming convention for the slot

```
void on_<widget name="">_<signal name="">(<signal parameters="">);
```

to make use of the auto connect feature.

Comment: There's no automatic connecting of slots. My guess would be that your connect() got called twice. If you connect the same signal twice to the same slot, the slot will we called twice when the signal is emitted once.

Comment: If @FrankOsterfeld is right, you could use [Qt::UniqueConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) to prevent it.

Comment: I saw automatic connection when your slot is named on_NAME_SIGNAL just like the designer names them. @tobi303 Try removing on_ , you should not get any signals anymore. Just look at the generated ui_*.h file. You should once see a connect there and once not.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld quite old q/a, but you might be interested in the blog I found