# Qt slot called twice

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a code with a QDoubleSpinBox

```
ui->doubleSpinBoxExposure->setMinimum(0.001);
ui->doubleSpinBoxExposure->setMaximum(1000);
ui->doubleSpinBoxExposure->setSingleStep(1.0);

connect(ui->doubleSpinBoxExposure, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),
        this, SLOT(OndoubleSpinBoxExposure_valueChanged(double)));

void WidgetCameraParameter::OndoubleSpinBoxExposure_valueChanged(double value)
{
    if (!camera)
        return;
    if (camera->isOpen())
    {        
        float exposure = static_cast<float>(value);
        float cameraExposure;
        camera->setExposure(exposure);
        LOG_INFO() <<" setting exposure to " << value << " ms";
        cameraExposure = camera->exposure();
        LOG_INFO() <<" resulting exposure is " << cameraExposure << " ms";
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I step up in the gui or down, this happens twice.
The starting parameter is value = 2. StepUp calls this function with 3, and directly afterwards with 4. And I have no idea why.

The stack trace is not helpfull:

> 1  WidgetCameraParameter::OndoubleSpinBoxExposure_valueChanged      widgetcameraparameter.cpp      311  0x406c17
>   2  WidgetCameraParameter::qt_static_metacall                        moc_widgetcameraparameter.cpp  110  0x40811f
>   3  QMetaObject::activate                                            qobject.cpp                    3771 0x12bc2e1
>   4  QMetaObject::activate                                            qobject.cpp                    3633 0x12bc575
>   5  QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged                                     moc_qspinbox.cpp               436  0x15e66190 
>   6  QDoubleSpinBoxPrivate::emitSignals                               qspinbox.cpp                   1112 0x15e663b2 
>   7  QAbstractSpinBoxPrivate::setValue                                qabstractspinbox.cpp           1741 0x15e6174d 
>   8  QAbstractSpinBox::stepBy                                         qabstractspinbox.cpp           643  0x15e62aba 
>   9  QAbstractSpinBox::timerEvent                                     qabstractspinbox.cpp           1246 0x15e5ffea 
>   10 QObject::event                                                   qobject.cpp                    1232 0x12bc918
>   11 QWidget::event                                                   qwidget.cpp                    9347 0x15d0c544 
>   12 QAbstractSpinBox::event                                          qabstractspinbox.cpp           795  0x15e65930 
>   13 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper                               qapplication.cpp               3727 0x15cc85ca 
>   14 QApplication::notify                                             qapplication.cpp               3690 0x15cd1f4f 
>   15 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2                                qcoreapplication.cpp           1048 0x1295119
>   16 QCoreApplication::sendEvent                                      qcoreapplication.h             234  0x12e4d87
>   17 QEventDispatcherWin32Private::sendTimerEvent                     qeventdispatcher_win.cpp       447  0x12e4d87
>   18 qt_internal_proc(HWND__ *, unsigned int, unsigned int, long) *16 qeventdispatcher_win.cpp       242  0x12e53d5
>   19 gapfnScSendMessage                                                                                   0x771162fa 
>   20 ??                                                                                                   0x5c0f30
>   21 USER32!GetThreadDesktop                                                                              0x77116d3a 
>   22 QEventDispatcherWin32Private::sendTimerEvent                     qeventdispatcher_win.cpp       456  0x12e4dc9
>   23 ??                                                                                                   0x5c0f30
>   24 USER32!CharPrevW                                                                                     0x771177c4 
>   25 USER32!DispatchMessageW                                                                              0x7711788a 
>   26 QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents                             qeventdispatcher_win.cpp       629  0x12e4ae8
>   27 QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents                        qwindowsguieventdispatcher.cpp 74   0x2496dab7 
>   28 QEventLoop::processEvents                                        qeventloop.cpp                 136  0x12937c8
>   29 QEventLoop::exec                                                 qeventloop.cpp                 214  0x1293c20
>   30 QCoreApplication::exec                                           qcoreapplication.cpp           1336 0x129c30e
>   31 QGuiApplication::exec                                            qguiapplication.cpp            1761 0x8461552
>   32 QApplication::exec                                               qapplication.cpp               2901 0x15cc84a9 
>   33 qMain                                                            main.cpp                       28   0x40183d
>   34 WinMain *16                                                      qtmain_win.cpp                 104  0x4094c5
>   35 main                                                                                                 0x4179ad

Any idea how to debug this further?

EDIT:
This only happens when I debug with breakpoints in the slot. Without the slot is only called once.
The second call of the slot does not happen from any function within the slot function, but only after the slot has ended from the event loop.

You can loop at the complete code:
https://github.com/pospiech/code/tree/master/libdev/devices/CameraViewer

Comment: maybe related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985844/why-is-my-mousepressevent-called-twice

Comment: @user463035818 Further info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections

Comment: on the other hand, it seems like the naming convention for auto connection requires a `on_` prefix while you have a `On`... anyhow try to remove the `connect` to see what happens. If thats the "problem" the fix is trivial

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-14259 ??

Comment: I've just tested this (without the camera stuff) and it works as expected, i.e. the slot is called only once per click, unless I press and hold. I am using Qt5.10.1.

Comment: If the connect is removed the slot is not called.

Comment: Maybe         `camera->setExposure(exposure);`
triggers the slot?

Comment: @JLev, that is easy to be tested. Let Matthias comment everything in the slot and put only one debug message. Basically my test was exactly the same.

Comment: I removed all code not needed for testing this issue. It can be tested without an actual camera (using a simulated one). It is reproducable. However - only with aktive debugging. If I run the same debug binary without debugging the problem does not occur. To me this looks like a Qt bug?! The camera interface does not trigger any slot. The spinbox is also not called after any command within the function, but only after the function is completed. The next trigger comes from the event loop not a function in my code.

Comment: I uploaded the code I am testing here to:https://github.com/pospiech/code/tree/master/libdev/devices/CameraViewer

Comment: Related to [pyQt: radioButton.isChecked() is executed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808257/pyqt-radiobutton-ischecked-is-executed-twice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `QStyle::StyleHint` enum, there is an interesting `SH_SpinBox_ClickAutoRepeatThreshold` constant. You can check its current value for your spin box, like this:

```
qDebug() << ui->doubleSpinBoxExposure->style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_SpinBox_ClickAutoRepeatThreshold);
```

This generally returns `500`, which is the number of milliseconds after which the auto repeat gets triggered (i.e. if the user holds the mouse press on the `up` spin button for longer than that threshold, the spin box value will start increasing continuously).

To see if you have a timing issue, try changing that value, using a custom `QStyle` class like this:

```
#include <QProxyStyle>

class MyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    int styleHint(StyleHint stylehint, const QStyleOption *opt, const QWidget *widget, QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const
    {
        if(stylehint == QStyle::SH_SpinBox_ClickAutoRepeatThreshold)
        {
            return 2000; //2 seconds threshold
        }
        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(stylehint, opt, widget, returnData);
    }
};
```

and setting an instance of it to the spin box style:

```
ui->doubleSpinBoxExposure->setStyle(new MyStyle());
```

Now it takes a lot (two long seconds) before the auto repeat gets triggered, and your issue should be gone, accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, this solves the problem. However the style is modified as well, which is not wanted. How can I keep the style?

Comment: Hi Matthias, I just provided some hints to debug the issue. If it happens at debug time only, and release builds are fine, just live with it (and don't bother editing the style the way I've shown). It happens because of debugging, which, generally speaking, slow down things, and can yield timing issues like yours.

Comment: Ok, that was also my approach, I just thought the style could be kept with simple adjustments in your code.

Comment: There was a mistake in my code, anyway (derive from QProxyStyle, not QCommonStyle). Edited.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a freezing gui-thread with your slot.
You can try this code in your slot

```
void WidgetCameraParameter::OndoubleSpinBoxExposure_valueChanged(double value)
{
#define NUM_LOOPS 1000000000
    qDebug() << value;
    quint64 i = NUM_LOOPS;
    while(i--);
}
```

To avoid this, you have to move to another thread an operation that consumes a lot of CPU time.

In debug mode its because of autorepeating timer.
Try this code to disable autorepeating in debug and, i think, you`ll understand:

*.h

...

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;
#endif
```

...

*.c

...

```
    ui->setupUi(this);
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    ui->doubleSpinBoxExposure->installEventFilter(this);
#endif
```

...

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
bool WidgetCameraParameter::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    QDoubleSpinBox *castSBox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(watched);
    if(castSBox && event->type()==QEvent::Timer)
    {
        QTimerEvent *tEvent = static_cast<QTimerEvent*>(event);
        if(tEvent)
            qDebug() << "<--QEvent::Timer-->" << tEvent->timerId();
        return true;
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(watched,event);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Why do you think the slot blocks? I am not seeing it.

Comment: There is nothing that freezes the gui. There is no load at all. This issue only happens when I debug the code with breakpoints. Wihtout the problem does not occur.

Comment: It is because of autorepeating timer, i think.

Comment: I didnt see that its only in debug-mode. Sorry.